# Flex validation popups no longer showing up in popup dialogs?

Tags: apache-flex, popup, validation

I am working on an application which has quite a bit of field-validation in it. The validation works great and I am 1000000% sure the validation message popups were appearing earlier. Now I did quite a bit of work and refactoring. One of the things I changed was the way I open up Popups/Dialog. In order to have these centered over the entire application instead of the opening component I refactored the way I open dialogs. I used the source of the Alert as a base for this but extended it quite a bit as I was having other issues (Focus Manager etc.) (I am just mentioning this as I am assuming that my missing popups are related to this).

Here comes the code responsible for opening popups in my application:

```
    public function show(realParent:Sprite,
                     displayParent:Sprite = null,
                     closeHandler:Function = null,
                     moduleFactory:IFlexModuleFactory = null):Dialog {

    // Get the parent ...
    // If none is set, use the top-level-application.
    if (!displayParent) {
        var sm:ISystemManager = ISystemManager(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManager);
        // no types so no dependencies
        var mp:Object = sm.getImplementation("mx.managers.IMarshallPlanSystemManager");
        if (mp && mp.useSWFBridge())
            displayParent = Sprite(sm.getSandboxRoot());
        else
            displayParent = Sprite(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication);
    }

    // Register for close-events, making sure the pop-up is closed.
    if (closeHandler != null) {
        this.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, closeHandler);
    }

    // Setting a module factory allows the correct embedded font to be found.
    if (moduleFactory) {
        this.moduleFactory = moduleFactory;
    } else if (realParent is IFlexModule) {
        this.moduleFactory = IFlexModule(realParent).moduleFactory;
    } else {
        if (realParent is IFlexModuleFactory) {
            this.moduleFactory = IFlexModuleFactory(realParent);
        } else {
            this.moduleFactory = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.moduleFactory;
        }

        // also set document if parent isn't a UIComponent
        if (!parent is UIComponent) {
            this.document = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.document;
        }
    }

    // Make the dialog center itself relative to the parent.
    PopUpManager.addPopUp(this, displayParent, true);
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);

    return this;
}
```

What could be responsible for the Validation popups not showing up any more? Where should I look?

Chris

Comment: Just ran your code: works fine in a simple (Spark) application. Are those fields in a module perhaps?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this line: `(!parent is UIComponent)` is not the same as `(!(parent is UIComponent))`. I believe the first statement will always evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Yes the Dialogs are opened in modules.

Comment: And I just checked ... in both cases (the one where the validaton message popups are shown and where they are not shown) the "realParent" was an "IFlexModule" and the first else-if is executed. But the difference is that in the working case the "realParent" is the skin of the Main application and in the not working one it's a module loaded by the main application.

Comment: Ok ... so I think I might be tracking down everyting. It turned out that obviously there was no relation to my changing of the owner of the popup, but much more one of the designers switching from mx:form to s:Form widgets exactly at the same time. If I use mx:Form elements instead of the spark equivalents I get the toolTips I was looking for. Any Idea why the spark form items don't show them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... so I figgured this out by myself again. I coould bang my head at the wall for taking so long for finding it though.

If I use the Spart forms, the FormItems and Forms themselves can define error text areas in order to output error messages. So as soon as the FormItem posesses a skin part with the id "errorTextDisplay" the error messages go there. I was now expecting that if there was no such part, the old notifications would be used ... nope.

After about 2-3 Hours of messing around with the code of FormItem and it's skins, I noticed that the "contentGroup" explicitly defined an attribute to suppress error tooltyips by setting showErrorTip to false. Simply removing the "errorTextDisplay" from the skin and changing the showErrorTip to true made my popups appear nicely :-)

Hopefully this post might help someone with the same problems.